# ASPX rerunning entire page code on event trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using EXT.NET with ASPX. I have never had this problem before. When I have an event trigger the page reruns all the code (though it does not actually "reload" the page). As far as I can see, this is not happening on all the other pages. Example code:

```
protected void gSelectApplied(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Ext.Net.ComboBox box = (Ext.Net.ComboBox)sender;
    string name = box.ID;
    switch (name)
    {
        case "gPreviousApplied":
            {
                gPreviousAppliedfunded.Hidden = box.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() == "Yes" 
                    ? false 
                    : true;
                break;
            }
        case "gPreviousAppliedfunded":
            {
                gPreviousApplied.Hidden = box.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() == "Yes"
                    ? false
                    : true;
                break;
            }

    }

}
```

This executes and is supposed to hide an element on the page. This however does not happen because it sets the hidden to true for a moment (not even visible) and then it gets reset back. When I set a breakpoint in the general page, it it hits the breakpoint upon triggering the event and THEN the event code itself.

The front end looks as such:

```
<ext:FormPanel ID="Sec5" runat="server" AutoHeight="true" BodyBorder="false"
            Layout="FormLayout" LabelAlign="Right" LabelPad="25" LabelWidth="220" Cls="blue"
            PaddingSummary="5px 0px 5px 115px" Border="false" BaseCls=".uData" Hidden="false">
            <Items>
                <ext:ComboBox FieldLabel="someField" ID="gPreviousApplied"
                    runat="server" OnDirectSelect="gSelectApplied">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:ListItem Text="Yes" />
                        <ext:ListItem Text="No" />
                    </Items>
                </ext:ComboBox>
                <ext:ComboBox FieldLabel="something" ID="gPreviousAppliedfunded"
                    runat="server">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:ListItem Text="Yes" />
                        <ext:ListItem Text="No" />
                    </Items>
                </ext:ComboBox>
                <ext:ComboBox FieldLabel="somethingelse" ID="gPreviousApplied" 
                    runat="server">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:ListItem Text="Yes" />
                        <ext:ListItem Text="No" />
                    </Items>
                </ext:ComboBox>
            </Items>
        </ext:FormPanel>
    </Items>
</ext:Panel>
```

Comment: What do you mean it is running all the code on the page again?  It should run all the code events for the page (init, load, pre render, etc.)  in accordance with the ASP.NET Page Life cycle.  Is it behaving differently than that?

Comment: did this event make all life cycle of the current page? get breakpoint on Render if it's go there. If not problem cause callback not postback.
Let us know what happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the autoeventwireup is set to false in aspx page.
Also check if there is anything in the page_load which sets the element back to false.
Use page.ispostback in page_load function